# Gksudo doesn't work at all

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

I'm trying to open Mousepad as root and I've typed in terminal "gksudo Mousepad" and when I enter my password in absolutely nothing opens. What do I do? I am running xUbuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

The command you are trying to type is "`mousepad`", not "`Mousepad`". Linux cares about case (upper/lower).

```
gksudo mousepad
```

will run `mousepad` as `root`. Your command,

```
gksudo Mousepad
```

will not find anything to run, and simply exit ("nothing happens").